# Salesforce update trigger error

Tags: apex, trigger

i need help as i am new to apex and trigger. i have created the below trigger to update the amount of existing record but it is giving me error

```
trigger discount on platform__c (after update) {
    List P1 = new list (); 
    Platform__C p2 = new Platform__C();

    for (platform__c p:trigger.new) {
        p2 = [select id,name,amount__c,opportunity__C from platform__c where ID=:p.ID];
        p2.amount__c=p.amount__c*20/100; 
        p1.add(P2);

    } 
    Update (P1); 
}
```

Comment: what kind of error does it gave ?

Comment: Your syntax isn't even correct...and this trigger causes recursive updates, so it can never work the way you have implemented it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: And make sure to use any kind of Query outside FOR loop only. If 1000 records are updating, it will cause an exception...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code introduces an infinite loop: the code will repeatedly try to update the same record. Instead, use a *before update* trigger to update the value in-place. **Keep in mind that the Amount__c field will be reduced by 80% with each edit.**

```
trigger discount on platform__c (before update) {
    for (platform__c p:trigger.new) {
        p.amount__c *= 0.2;
    }
}
```

The changes to Trigger.new will be persisted to the database automatically when using "before insert"/"before update".

Comment: If that's all the trigger does, it should really be WFR.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need an after update trigger to do what you do in your trigger. A before update trigger will be perfectly suitable.

```
trigger discount on platform__c (before update) {
    for (platform__c p:trigger.new) {
        p.amount__c=p.amount__c*20/100; 
    } 
}
```

Hope it helps.